# Verify there is a combination of unique string

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, data-structures

```
class Details{
 String name;
 String age;
 String email;
 String location;
}
```

1) If there is List of Details as in `List<Details>` how to verify for a combination of name and email collectively unique. (i.e) For a single email address there cant be two name entry.

2) How to verify the combination of all fields in the class file is unique.

what would be a perfect data structure to address this ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hash values by a separator like `#`, and then find that all uniques or not. Hash value for a `Details` is `name + "#" + "email` in the first case, and is `name + "#" + age + "#" + email + "#" + location` in the second case.
You can using `Hashmap` to find duplicates if there is any with the specified key (or hash) for each instance of `Details`.

Comment: why do we need a # here ?

Comment: @Sree because if you have `name = om` and `email = g@e.c`, it has the same hash for `name = o` and `email = mg@e.c`! Hence, you need a separator which does not exist in `name` and `email`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to achieve unique values-only, you should use [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). You have to use your own equals & hashCode implementation, for example, for case 1):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Details details = (Details) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, details.name) &&
            Objects.equals(email, details.email);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(name, email);
}
```

If you need all Details members to be unique just update hash & equals implementation with needed properties.

Answer (score 3):

When you overrides an equals method within any object, you can perfectly check the equality of that Object with another one *even though they are residing somewhere different within the memory.*

*So the below code*

> myList.contains(myObject);

will respond if there is an object within myList that the equals method return true with myObject.

In all major IDEs (like intelliJ, netbeans, eclipse, etc) the IDE will help you to override the equals method accurately. here is the auto-generated code for overriding equals method using **intelliJ IDE**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Details details = (Details) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, details.name) &&
            Objects.equals(email, details.email);
}
```

*Now if you want to avoid duplicate to be added inside your List, you should use **Set** instead of a **List**.* A **Set** will add a new element **if the combination** of *hashCode* and *equals* method are different (comparing the existing object and newly intended to add object)

So we have to override hashCode method (generated by intelliJ IDE) *if we want to use a flavor of **Set** class*:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, email);
}
```

now if you create a Set and try to add two objects with similar name and email inside that Set, the set will only add the first unique name and email address, **even thou the other fields of the second object have different values**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

class Details {
    String name;
    String age;
    String email;
    String location;

    public Details(String name, String age, String email, String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Details details = (Details) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, details.name) &&
                Objects.equals(email, details.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, email);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(name: %s, age: %s, email: %s, location: %s)", name, age, email, location);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Details> mySet = new HashSet<>();
        mySet.add(new Details("Mehdi", "12", "123@xyz.com", "Los Angeles"));
        mySet.add(new Details("Mehdi", "34", "123@xyz.com", "Las Vegas"));
        System.out.println(mySet);
    }

}
```

**This is the whole test app.** There is something else that worth mentioning. if in any case you have saved your data inside a list and you want to remove the duplicate based on the rules you have (ex name, email) You can try this approach:

```
Set<Details> mySet = new HashSet<>(myList);
```

*Which myList is your list.* so in your app that will be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Details> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new Details("Mehdi", "12", "123@xyz.com", "Los Angeles"));
    myList.add(new Details("Mehdi", "34", "123@xyz.com", "Las Vegas"));

    Set<Details> mySet = new HashSet<>(myList);
    System.out.println(mySet);
}
```

and here is the result without any duplicate:

> [(name: Mehdi, age: 12, email: 123@xyz.com, location: Los Angeles)]

Answer (score 1):

Besides of using a hash as propposed by @OmG, you could also use a **TreeSet** with the key being a concatenation of the unique fields, also using a separator between them.

A `Set` only admits unique keys.